# What do string theorists mean when they say that little is known about M theory?

Tags: string-theory

1. It’s often said that we don’t know what M theory is, but what does that actually mean?
2. And how long until M theory becomes somewhat of an understood theory?
3. Where are we at now with M theory?

Comment: I think this is a little broad, especially 3., as you're basically asking for a review of a the entire topic of M theory.

Comment: But I think there is a good question here - if string theorists don't know what M theory is, what do they mean by it and why's it so important? and what would it take for them to say 'we know what M theory is'?

Answer (score 2):

So far, it is known the low-energy limit of the theory. This means that when the energy scale is not high enough to resolve the typical length of the theory, then we will just see point-like objects. Namely, at that energy scale, our system is effectively a set of particles and it will be described by standard quantum field theory. In M-theory, this quantum field theory is 11-dimensional supergravity [(see this entry for further details)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28742/derivation-of-the-supergravity-action-in-11d), which contains Einstein's theory.

In addition, it is also known that 11D supergravity, when compactified on a circle, gives rise to the corresponding supergravity that describes the low-energy limit of type IIA string theory.

Comment: What would it take for experts to say 'we know M theory'? A particular Lagrangian/action from which superstring theories can be derived? A new formalism entirely?

Comment: They would need a Lagrangian, or a set of operators that describes the theory even at a non-perturbative level. This is something that even in string theories is not known: we just have a perturbative description of the theories.